# Selenium Python Upload a picture to Facebook

Tags: api

please help, I want to upload a picture, I tried a lot, it is not useful

bugh = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[3]/form/div[6]/div/button[1]/div/div[1]/i")))#.click()
bugh.send_keys(r'N:\g\kkkp.png')

Comment: Selenium Python Upload a picture to Facebook

Comment: Can you post the error message you're receiving?